# A simple shortcut to start nslookup, do a command and then be ready to accept further

Tags: batch-file, nslookup

I've been trying to create a shortcut to do something that should be simple.

1) Open CMD
2) run nslookup
3) set the server to google (8.8.8.8)
4) then run "set type=all"
5) be ready to accept user inputs (domains)

I have a shortcut that runs cmd.exe with "cmd.exe /k nslookup - 8.8.8.8 & set type=all" but the set type command doesn't run.

I've tried making an nsinput.txt file that simply contains:
"set type=all"

But if I use that as input for cmd.exe ("cmd.exe /k nslookup - 8.8.8.8 < nsinput.txt")

Then it looks like it runs the command but exits out of nslookup right after.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Try simple `nslookup -type=all - 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Hah, that works! Thank you!